# Why I am not able to clear custom text field in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have custom text field, and when I typing text I want to clear text inside of the text field by clear button, I did not find any solution, I am try to solve by similar question, but  still same problem, any idea?

**view:**

```
struct TextView : View {
    
    @State var text = ""

  var body: some View{
        
        VStack {

         CustomTxt(txt: self.$txt)

                              Button(action: {

                    txt = ""
                
                    
                }, label: {
                    
                    Image("clear text field")
                    
                    
                })
      }
   }
```

**textfield:**

```
struct CustomTxt : UIViewRepresentable {
    
    
    @Binding var txt : String
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return ResizableTextField.Coordinator(parent1: self)
    }
    
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let view = UITextView()
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        return view
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.height = uiView.contentSize.height
        }
    }
    
    class Coordinator : NSObject, UITextViewDelegate {
        var parent : CustomTxt
        
        init(parent1 : CustomTxt) {
            parent = parent1
        }
        
        func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
            if self.parent.txt == "" {
                textView.text = ""

            }
        }
        
        func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.parent.height = textView.contentSize.height
                self.parent.txt = textView.text
            }
        }
    }
    
   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When binding is changed the `UIViewRepresentable.updateUIView` is called, so you have to updated wrapped UIKit view there.

In your case it is

```
func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
    uiView.text = txt            // << here !!
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.height = uiView.contentSize.height
    }
}
```

thus tap button result in update wrapped UITextView with empty string.